# Keeping track of an item in List Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm .net newbie starting one project for fun.
I'm using list box filled with some city names so user can pick one.
Every city class has name and UID. How do I know which city user clicked on?
Obviously, I can get text of selected item, run through city list and
find one by name but that seems stupid.

Is there equivalent to MFC SetItemDataPtr type of thing or what is
the most common way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to a WinForms [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx), this can be done in the following way.

Instead of setting the `Items` of the `ListBox` to an array/collection of strings (as I presume you are currently doing), you could rather set it to an collection of a user-defined type (`City` in your case), and then use the [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) property (set to `Name` or whatever the property of your `City` class that you want to display), so that each item in the `ListBox` can actually be accessed as the user-defined `City` object, while it is still displayed by its `Name` property.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ListView (in details mode) instead of a ListBox. Then you could use the Tag property of ListViewItem which is the equivalent of MFC's SetItemDataPtr.

Comment: I was just searching for this :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the item selected by user by following code:

```
list1.SelectedItem;

//text -> list1.SelectedItem.Text
//value-> list1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the ListBox with an own-defined type of an item, since it accepts an `Object`, preferably implementing a `ToString()` method. It can be an object with ID and Name properties so they can be accessed with ListBox's `SelectedItem` property.